# Writing dynamic VBA code as in selecting only data in a column instead of blank field

Tags: vba, excel

i am still new in excel vba, i have some difficulties to modify the code in order to make in dynamic as to only select field with data only instead of blank field ( in a column).

`Sub SaveFile()
Sheets("2008").Range("V3:V6500").Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A6500").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub`

Let say if the data in column v3 is less than 6500 row, there will be a lot of blank space, if the data exceed 6500 row, the data can't be copy from sheets to sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub SaveFile()
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Sheets("2008").Range("V3:V" & LastRow).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
End Sub
```

Have not tested it, but I think the paste will be dynamic in size

Edit.. you may need to change

```
With activesheet
```

To

```
With Sheets("2008")
```

If you don't run the macro from 2008 sheet.

Comment: yeah, this works flawlessly, after i changed it to sheets("2008"). Thank you so much